# Showing most liked post within the past week

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I've run into an interesting issue while trying to display most liked posts over the past week.

Here's the desired process: Editor posts a new article and users can come in and "like" the post. I want the "most liked" posts over the past week show at the top of the feed. This functionality works great right now, however, after 4-5 days these posts vanish from the feed as if there is some code only allowing the posts to be displayed on the feed for a certain length of time.

Ideally, if a post were to start "trending" a few months after posting, it should show up in the feed. But right now that doesn't happen. If I were to like a post that was uploaded 4-5 days ago, it doesnt show up on the "trending feed", this feed only displays trending posts that were posted within the last few days. If that makes sense?

Here is the code that I am using to generate this feed:

```
function jm_most_popular_week() {
    global $post;
    $week = date('W'); 
    $year = date('Y');
    $args = array(
      'year' => $year,
      'week' => $week,
      'post_type' => array( 'post', 'enter-your-comma-separated-post-types-here' ),
      'meta_key' => '_post_like_count',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'posts_per_page' => 5
    );
    $pop_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $pop_posts->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $pop_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $pop_posts->the_post();
        echo get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
      }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
```

I used this as reference: https://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/wordpress-post-like-system/

EDIT: here is the site im using it on, you can switch to most recent posts by changing the dropdown tab from "fresh finds" (this is where I want the functionality) to "most recent": http://uncvrd.co/

Comment: you want to show post that was published last week or any post that was published before current week?

Comment: @RaunakGupta I want any post to show (no matter the date it was published) on the feed sorted by the most liked within the past week. I added a link to my site at the bottom. Now switch the feed to "most recent" by clicking the dropdown next to "Discovery Mode" these are all of the latest posts. You can "like" a post by clicking on the lightning bolt symbol on the right hand side. Now that this track has been liked, it should show up on the "fresh finds feed" but do you see how the only post that shows up there is the one that I posted today?

Comment: If you want to get post from any time then you don't need to use `year` and `week` arguments. Try by removing those argument it will work.

Comment: nailed it! Thanks @RaunakGupta, if you post this as answer, I would be happy to choose it as the correct one. Thanks for spotting the mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to show post form any time so you don't need to supply argument `year` and `week` to [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters). Try by removing those argument it will work.

Hope this helps!